How to make a session that doesn't have combat, NPC's or dialog?
My group will be heading into a strange, alien wilderness that will have no NPC's, no dialog and no combat.
Without the back and forth or dialogue, meeting new characters, etc. I'm having trouble writing enough content to keep them busy for a 3 hour session.
My current ideas include scavenging for food and water. Plants can terrain could be dangerous. But most scenarios can be overcome by simple Stat checks.
Any ideas?

Hello and welcome. Your question is interesting, but Q&A format is not particularly good for idea generation where every answer is equally valid.

That's fair. Is there a different place that would work better for this question?

Take a look at this meta post https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/10642
